# How do I determine my New York pension category?

Tags: united-states, taxes, retirement, new-york, form-1099

I am filing my 2023 tax return for New York with H&R Block. When I import my 1099-R form for my retirement plan with Transamerica, I am asked to select a category for my New York pension. The options are:

- Not Applicable
- Federal Government Pension (Excl Military)
- State / Local Qualified Pension
- Private Retirement Benefits
- Military Retirement Benefits

I do not work for the the military or federal government, but I don't know if my pension would be private, state qualified, or not applicable.

How can I tell what category my pension falls under when filing taxes for New York State?

[image]

Comment: Was your employer a State or local government agency?

Comment: @littleadv No, it was not.

Comment: So... what's unclear?

Comment: If you don't know otherwise, it's a private pension.